# Aptana Studio 3 What is a workspace

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Could some one explain to me what a Workspace space is in Aptana and how to use them?  My main problem is that I don't even understand the concept of the Workspace and I can find no documentation anywhere (and I've looked quite a lot) that explains this.

Sorry if sounds like a stupid question but I want to try using an IDE rather than Notepad++ to see if I like it and I'm really stuck on what the concept of a Workspace is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workspace is place you adding your projects. Aptana is built on eclipse, so you can read about workspace in eclipse. http://archive.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/01/getting-friendly-with-eclipse-workspaces.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that it has been helpful, it's also good to know that it is based on Eclipse so can look around for documentation / posts about that to find out about Aptana.

Answer (score 4):

Workspace is the area where you load all your current active projects. It makes it easier for you to access them at one place rather than always have to navigate to your project directory. As an example, you may have a zend project in your zend framework directory but another HTML project sitting in your public directory. These two projects will be inside your workspace such that a single click in them brings the entire project to the side bar.